# ngx-scorm-wrapper does not support NgModule

Tags: angular, angularjs, scorm

Im trying to create a sample angular project with SCORM, I installed the ngx-scorm-wrapper and tried to import it as below:

```javascript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ScormWrapperService } from 'ngx-scorm-wrapper';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ScormWrapperService,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I am getting the following compile error:

```
'ScormWrapperService' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
scorm-wrapper.service.d.ts(5, 16): This likely means that the library (ngx-scorm-wrapper) which declares ScormWrapperService is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

This is a completely new project
I tried the following:

- creating a project in different versions of angular (altho I want to use the latest version).
- clean the cache and npm install again
- adding the "postinstall": "ngcc" in package-lock.json

Would very appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: after two weeks and I still havent found a solution, can anyone give a thought about this?